# Regarding t test (comparing investment strategies)

Tags: time-series, t-test, neweywest

I have two time series. These series consists of monthly returns of two investment strategies. I want to test that whether second investment strategy significantly perform better than first one.

For this purpose I subtract returns of first strategy from returns of second strategy and on that difference I applied newey-west t test. Is this an adequate approach. If this is not adequate, please tell me what i should do.